# Outlook contacts: View custom fields created by mobile phone

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, contacts

Samsung Galaxy phones implement somewhat different contact record structure than the one found in typical Outlook contact. It allows custom fields and saves them as [custom fields supported by Exchange server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61218907/2392157). Can I somewhat achieve displaying these fields in the Outlook?

**Details:**

For example, Samsung allows *three* Instant Messenger Addresses (not only one) to be stored with contact, for example these sample values:

```
IMAddress1
IMAddress2
IMAddress3
```

[image: See the screen snippet from (Samsung) Contacts app on the phone.]

When I inspect this contact in Outlook 2019, I see the following field and value:

```
IM Address: IMAddress1
```

[image: See the screen snippet from Outlook 2019 in Windows 10.]

`IMAddress2` and `IMAddress3` are not visible in the UI, even if I check list of all fields or list of user-defined fields, which is shown as empty.

If I save the contact as VCF file, only `IMAddress1` is listed. However, if I save the contact as MSG file, all *three* values can be seen in the binary content.

How can I display true list of all fields stored in Outlook contact?

Answer (score -1):

The fields you can import data to using the Outlook import wizard are limited to the ones that you see in the Outlook field map which does not include all fields - i.e.

A similar [case](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/importexport-wont-export-im-details/11b1ac9b-2f46-48ad-a3d7-f99008afd9aa) for your reference.

Comment: Hi, in my case, the fields already *are* in Outlook (so we are not discussing import), but they are hidden. The question is, how to display and access them using Outlook UI.